# Making an Oracle query between three tables using INNER JOIN

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm working with a super inconsistent Oracle database and I need help to make a query.

Simplyfying the database to an example I have these three tables.

```
TABLE_F
------
id = 3
title = "Hello"


TABLE_M
------
id = 3
category = "val3"
flid = 5


TABLE_X
------
id = 3
body = "How are you?"
flid = 30

id = 3
body= "Bye bye"
flid = 35
```

I want to make a query to get the following result:

```
id | title | mat | BODY          |  OTHER 
------------------------------------------
3    helllo  val3  How are you?    Bye bye
```

My query is:

```
SELECT
TABLE_F.title,
TABLE_M.category,
TABLE_X.body as BODY
FROM TABLE_F
INNER JOIN TABLE_M
ON TABLE_F.id=TABLE_M.id
INNER JOIN TABLE_X
ON TABLE_F.id=TABLE_X.id
WHERE TABLE_M.flid=5 AND TABLE_X.flid=30;
```

Where I get:

```
id | title | mat | BODY         
--------------------------------
3    helllo  val3  How are you?
```

I need to add to the query the `TABLE_X.body as OTHER` (which contains the "*Bye bye*" string), BUT I can't do it as I'm filtering witd `flid=30` in order to get the body.

It's not my database and I can't change the design. I need to get that desired output with one query (which I dont know if it's possible).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: join twice the TABLE_X with flid=35

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join table_x two times  using alias

```
SELECT_F.id, 
  TABLE_F.title,
  TABLE_M.category  mat,
  TABLE_X.body  BODY,
  Y.body  OTHER BODY,  
FROM TABLE_F
  INNER JOIN TABLE_M ON TABLE_F.id=TABLE_M.id
  INNER JOIN TABLE_X ON TABLE_F.id=TABLE_X.id AND TABLE_X.flid=30
  INNER JOIN TABLE_X Y ON TABLE_F.id=Y.id AND Y.flid=35
```